# Plotting a curve on a set of points two different curves are shown?

Tags: matplotlib, python-3.6, data-fitting

I have a set of data I fitted with a second-order polynomial. Then I plot the data points with plt.scatter() and the resulting fit curve with plt.plot(). The strange thing is that I see TWO curves on the graph while the resulting fit parameters are just 3 (that is to say ONE second-order polynomial). I can't understand. I also tried to plot the curve using the same parameters on another piece of program and I get just one curve as I expected to be. Anyone con help? Thanks

here the piece of program from which I get 2 curves

this is what peaks looks like -> [1721.64052934 3791.89782429 4285.67013482  837.99662477 1949.75202969
  250.4119814 ]

```
peaks = np.asarray(peaks)
sigma_peaks = np.asarray(sigma_peaks)

x = [511,1173.237,1332.501,215.98,583.20,59.54]
x = np.asarray(x)

plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.scatter(x,peaks,label='data')
params, params_covariance = optimize.curve_fit(fitmodel.pol1, x, peaks)
print(params)
perr  = np.sqrt(np.diag(params_covariance))
print(perr)
plt.plot(x, fitmodel.pol1(x, *params), label='fit', color = 'red')
plt.ylabel('Peak position')
plt.xlabel('Energy (keV)')
plt.grid()
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: You are aware that your `x` is not sorted? In case of a scatter plot that does not matter but for the normal plot it does. For plotting the fit I'd create a more dense list anyway.

Comment: Sorting worked! I actually realized the lists were not sorted but I thought it wouldn't be a problem because every x was linked to the right y.  Thank you so much.